# Sharepoint Online Excel Web Access does not works in IE with Publishing enabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-web-access-webpart

It Appears that SharePoint Online Excel Web Access does not works in IE with Publishing enabled. The fields are blank whereas the same works fine in Edge/Chrome.

Could someone please confirm that this is a known limitation or provide details on what needs to be done in order to function correctly in IE.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems to be a browser issue.

In general, for browser issues, you can do the followings:
1. Add the site into IE Trusted Sites
2. Add your site into Compatibility view
3. Clear IE browser cache
4. Run use IE 10 Mode

If none of the above works, you can consider opening a ticket from Microsoft for help